# Multiple way of getting a Traverser from neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is there any difference between

**Approach 1:**

```
   TraversalDescription one = new TraversalDescriptionImpl();
        one = one.breadthFirst()
             .relationships(RelType.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING)
             .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition());
    Traverser t1 = one.traverse(node);
```

**Approach 2:**

```
    TraversalDescription two = Traversal.description()
            .breadthFirst()
            .relationships(RelType.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING)
            .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition());

    Traverser t2 = one.traverse(node);
```

Both Traversers seem to deliver the same results. Is there one approach preferred over another? When and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object of the class `TraversalDescriptionImpl` is what the factory class `Traversal` will return when calling `Traversal.description()`.  Snipped from the `Traversal` class source:

```
public static TraversalDescription description() {
    return new TraversalDescriptionImpl();
}
```

Hence,

```
TraversalDescription one = new TraversalDescriptionImpl();
```

is the same as

```
TraversalDescription two = Traversal.description()
```